# javascript at top of my pages not coded in Webpages

Tags: html

I put up a webpage and look at it online and see a javascript that I didn't put there. Anyone know what it is and what it is doing?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        Math.random = function(a, c, d, b) {
            return function() {
                return 300 > d++ ? (a = (1103515245 * a + 12345) % b, a / b) : c()
            }
        }(1923656340, Math.random, 0, 1 << 21);
        (function() {
            function b() {
                try {
                    if (top.window.location.href == c && !0 != b.a) {
                        var a = -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') ? new XDomainRequest : new XMLHttpRequest;
                        a.open('GET',

                        http: //1.2.3.4/cserver/clientresptime?       cid=CID5102662.AID1371143442.TID25950&url='+encodeURIComponent(c)+'&resptime='+(new Date-d)+'&starttime='+d.valueOf(),!0);a.send(null);b.a=!0}}catch(e){}}var d=new Date,a=window,c=document.location.href,f='undefined';f!=typeof a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent('onload',b):f!=typeof a.addEventListener&& a.addEventListener('load',b,!1)})();/* ]]}> */
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: You have an infected site or an evil host.

Answer (score 3):

This may be injection code from something like HughesNet or other provider. http://www.webproworld.com/webmaster-forum/threads/127543-Mystery-Javascript http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Is-http-1-2-3-4-bmi-int-js-bmi-js-version-1332944399-safe-a/td-p/751780

Comment: Confirmed presence of script using HughesNet on: 2016-03-31  Strangely enough, at times it's not present in the source of certain page loads.